# PayPal API, finding the right one

Tags: c#, asp.net, transactions, paypal

I need to add the option to pay with PayPal in my web site.
I would like to have a API where i can send PayPal the information and get back right away the transaction ID so i can save it in my DB.
What API will be best for me? Is  there a way to do this? I saw they have this list:

[list](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/use-cases/)

Also do you know were i can find good examples for this? my app is ASP.NET c#
I know this a very beginner question, what i really need help with this.

Thank you

**EDIT**
I started working with something but then found a problem I posted a new question here
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829960/setexpresscheckout-returns-null-token-in-asp-net-only-on-some-computers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is simple Credit Card and PayPal Wallet payments - just use our new Restful Payment APIs - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

They are much more cleaner and simple APIs to begin with if that's all the payment functionality you need.

Comment: I need the option to receive the transactionId back from Paypal, is that possible with the Restful Payment APIs?
Also can you please take a look at my new question I posted today, It will be a big help if you can help me with that one.
[new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829960/setexpresscheckout-returns-null-token-in-asp-net-only-on-some-computers)

Comment: yes - the new Rest APIs provide you the transactions (Sale or Authorization or Capture or Refund).

Comment: Thank you! I tried looking in to the Restful Payment APIs but got a little lost. do you know where i can find a small and easy to understand example?

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/ and https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

And the API reference here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/453595/Paypal-Integration-in-asp-net

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/474197/PayPal-Gateway-Integration-in-ASP-NET

http://paypaldeveloper.blogspot.in/2009/02/how-to-integration-paypal-with-aspnet-c.html

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article928-online-payments-using-paypal-integration-with-aspnet.aspx

I hope these links will help you.. :)

Comment: Thank you! do you know of any specific example that implements how to get the transactionID back form payPal right after the transaction is made?

Comment: See when you post the data to paypal site (in json format), then in response you get the transactionId.

Comment: This is very important for me, I need to know in what stage do i post the extra data to paypal (and what is the data), and when do i get it back? I tried to use PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID but its always null. can you help?

Comment: can you please tell me how are you proceeding with the integration, so that i can rectify the issue. :)

Comment: I found something that works, but then on some computers it wont work. I posted a new question here [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829960/setexpresscheckout-returns-null-token-in-asp-net-only-on-some-computers) can you please take a look?

Answer (score 1):

There is an up-to-date sample code for PayPal C# api on that page [PayPal C# API](http://www.thecodenode.com/PayPalAPICSharpdotNetWrapper.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for beginners integrating with HTML API PayPal is probably the easiest and best way to get started.

This article is slightly outdated, but explains that option along with others in straightforward matter:

Introduction to PayPal for C# - ASP.NET developers
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers